# Incrementing the row and Deleting a row using vba IN EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

```
                Range("H25")
```

The above statement selects the 25th row of H column.Now The thing I want to know is,
How do i increment the row putting H constant?
 yeah I have seen these on the google $h24 where column stays constant and row keeps on incrementing.

But i have to increment it from H25 to the end I dont know where does H column end. how do i make that?We can declare a variable right using VBA and incremenet it?

```
   I was thinkin to put it like these Range("Hvariablename")?
```

The actual Task I need to do is I have to check rows from H25 to the end and get their values to my VBA and make some calcutaions then right it back to them Im stucked at incrementing the rows.And could anyone please let me know the macro to delete a row from the vba itself?Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can provide some further details about how this range is supposed to looks like. When you mean "have to check rows from H25 to the end and" what's the END here?

If you're manually copying the formula down, it will automatically goes until the last row with values in column G. Is that your case? I'm not assuming the H rows below row 25 already have some values. Is this the case?

If you use as END the last row with values in column G, you can use `Selection.AutoFill`.

If you already have values in column H and want to go through them, you can define a dynamic range and loop through it in VBA.

To define a dynamic range: Add a new range, based in this formula (you may need to adapt it according to your needs, obviously)
`=OFFSET(Sheet1!$H$25,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$H:$H),1)`

And then, in VBA, go through it.

```
Sub TEST()

    Dim oCell As Excel.Range
    Dim oRange As Excel.Range

    Set oRange = [TestRange]

    For Each oCell In oRange

        Debug.Print oCell.VALUE

    Next oCell

End Sub
```

In time: To delete an entire row in Excel, you'll use

```
Sheets(1).Rows(25).EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

A Do While() Loop sounds like what you might need.

```
Do While(cells(row,col)<>"")
      'Some code to be executed on cell(row,col)
Loop
```

Or you could do the same thing with for loop

and find the last cell using `lastRow=Cells("H24").End(xlDown).Row`.  (It is the same thing as pressing Ctrl+Down. so if there are empty cells between cell H25 and the end you will need to account for that).

Either way I'd definitely look into using the R1C1 cell reference style for moving through cells instead of the A1 style. You moving through lettered columns is much more difficult than numbered columns. Also you should keep in mind that the "last row" in Excel 2007 is a very high number and looping all the way until the end can take a lot longer than looping until the last important cell.

I hope that's on the right track.